# Copy file handle so that there are two independent handles to the same file

Tags: python, file, unix

I have a Python program which does the following:

- It takes a list of files as input
- It iterates through the list several times, each time opening the files and then closing them

What I would like is some way to open each file at the beginning, and then when iterating through the files make a copy of each file handle. Essentially this would take the form of a copy operation on file handles that allows a file to be traversed independently by multiple handles. The reason for wanting to do this is because on Unix systems, if a program obtains a file handle and the corresponding file is then deleted, the program is still able to read the file. If I try reopening the files by name on each iteration, the files might have been renamed or deleted so it wouldn't work. If I try using `f.seek(0)`, then that might affect another thread/generator/iterator.

I hope my question makes sense, and I would like to know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: I think you are worrying too much, why would another program randomly delete a file that you are using from Python? Also, generally file delete/rename generally does not happen if it is open in some program.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get a copy of a file handle, you would need to use POSIX `dup` system call.  In python, that would be accessed by using `os.dup` - [see docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).  If you have a file *object* (e.g. from calling `open()`), then you need to call `fileno()` method to get file descriptor.

So the entire code will look like this:

```
with open("myfile") as f:
    fd = f.fileno()       # get descriptor
    fd2 = os.dup(fd)      # duplicate descriptor
    f2 = os.fdopen(fd2)   # get corresponding file object
```